# Serial Bus Handling

Tags: serial

Multi receive topology is used like connecting one TX(sensor) to two RX(computers). My question is it also possible to connect two TX(computers) to one RX (sensor).

Comment: There is not enough information in this question. (1) Which device is transmitting - the sensor or the computer? (2) What is the sensor? Link to datasheet? (Please put the extra information _in the question_ and not in the comments.)

Comment: Please put the information **in your question** as it can not be answered as is. It still doesn't make sense. Are you asking, "(1) Can two computers receive data from one RS422 sensor? (2) Can both computers program the one RS422 sensor?". Again, please fix your question.

Comment: Huh? What? I have no idea what a "fpv project" is supposed to be, how exactly this sensor is supposed to be connected to two other "FC" (whatever that is) things, and the last sentence is hopelessly garbled at best.  Try asking in English.  Until then, closing this mess.

Comment: @OlinLathrop try to understand and ask what is not clear if your intention to help. It seems opposite. So you are useless here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a stab at it here, I don't think you will be able to run a redundant system just with the connections you have described. Only one computer can be the RS-422 master at one time and the other computer will not know when to become the master when the other computer fails. You could make a third computer to be the RS-422 master, but then you have just lost your redundancy. If the third computer is a much more robust system that monitors the two computers, then there may be some benefit.

Edit: now that you mention a CAN bus also, yes that would allow it to work but there are still some major design hurdles to get it to work the way you want it to, it's not just a simple matter of connecting it a certain way. 1. you will need custom circuitry to physically reconfigure the RS-422 bus to change the master. Remember the master is what physically drives the voltages on the bus. 2. you will need to run self checks on each computer and pass a check value regularly onto the bus to be stored in each computer's RAM. When a condition occurs that indicates to one of the computers that the other is non functioning it should attempt to reconfigure the RS-422 bus so that it becomes the master.

Comment: First thanks for effort Sır. You said "computer will not know" is not true as there is also a CAN bus interface between computers. According this info can you edit response. Just looking a solution simply connect computers tx+- nodes to sensor rx+-. Thanks.

Comment: Yes a CAN bus can assist but there are still a number of hurdles to get it to work the way you want it to, see my edit.

Comment: I think the simplest way to do it is to make both computers the RS-422 master, and design a circuit with two RS-422 slaves that both receive the data from the flight sensor.

Comment: They will run on separate RS-422 buses, and have two slave devices both getting information from the sensor. You would need to design a special circuit for the sensor to drive the two slaves. Does the sensor have to run RS-422? Do the computers have to run RS-422? I think RS-485 would suit your system better, or just a CAN bus on the sensor?